# JDBC connection without database definition

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a class wich connects to MySQL database. I want to make it more universal. I'm not sure in myself. My class can connect any server if you specify the database name.

```
String url="jdbc:mysql://"+host+":"+port+"/"+dbname;
```

Can someone tell me, how can I connect without the specifying the database name(to use create database command for example)? Is it correct to use:

```
String url="jdbc:mysql://"+host+":"+port
```

or it uses other syntax? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can use `String url="jdbc:mysql://"+host+":"+port` but during the execution of query you need to specify the `database` name as

```
select * from dbname.table
```

Comment: I believe with MySQL you can also use `setCatalog()` on the connection to set the 'current' database.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the `database` parameter may be omitted:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port;
```